# Stripe Payment Using Firebase Cloud Funtions Pricing for Live App React Naive

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

i have implemented `Stripe payment gateway` using `Firebase Cloud Functions` in react native.    When i test it locally it's worked perfect. payment succeeds but when i go live url , payment can't process due to outbound networking

> You can't integrate with Stripe using Cloud Functions on the free
>   plan, because that plan has a limitation where it's not able to make
>   outgoing connections to endpoints that are not fully controlled by
>   Google. This is set in place in order to prevent abuse. You will have
>   to provide billing information and upgrade to a paid plan.

My Question to Firebase Users is that as a company:

1. How much i have to pay for this per/month or per year ?
2. Also is this secure or not ?
3. And From where i can pay Firebase to able to process live url.

Comment: It seems you are using `Spark` plan. So, you have to upgrade to `Flame` or `Blaze` plan to make it works. For testing, I think you can use `Blaze` plan, so you can use free usage from `Spark` plan

Answer (score 0):

The cost of Cloud Functions is purely based on how much you use it, not on the time period that you use it. For full details I recommend studying the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), and use the calculator at the bottom of that page. But you can get started without paying, as the Blaze plan has the same free quota that you on the free Spark plan. You'll only start paying for Firebase usage when you go beyond that free quota.

You can upgrade (and later downgrade) your project to the paid plan from the pricing page, or by clicking the <kbd>upgrade</kbd> link at the bottom left of your Firebase console.